# How to import Derby source code into eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, derby

Actually, I've tried netbeans and it works. But I prefer eclipse.
So, is there any way to import the derby source code into eclipse?

Comment: In think you cannot but You can create a new project in Eclipse and copy the source code and libraries required. That's what worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the page that desrcibes fully how to do that:
http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/BuildingDerby

It works for me.